# Only output embedded documents that exist in other document mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pipeline, aggregation

I have written an aggregation pipeline that up to now returns 2 documents (after matching, projecting and grouping) that look something like this:

```
{"_id": "group1",
        "items": [
            {
                ...item1 fields...
            },
            {
                ...item2 fields...
            },
            ....
        ]
},
{"_id": "group2",
        "items": [
            {
                ...item1 fields...
            },
            {
                ...item3 fields...
            },
            ....
        ]
}
```

The results always have these 2 groups and both groups have an array with items. I want to extend this pipeline in a way so that I only get the items that are common in the two arrays. For the example above, only item1 would be returned.
Any ideas?

Comment: I believe I should have handled the aggregation pipeline differently up to this point.